# How does the variable "pxe_default_server" get set in Red Hat 7.9?

Tags: redhat, dhcp, pxe-boot, rhel7

We have a RHEL 7.9 server that is acting as a DHCP/TFTP (PXE) server servicing multiple subnets. Below is a copy of our dhcpd.conf file (the DHCP/PXE server is X.Y.145.98):

```
allow bootp;
allow booting;
max-lease-time 1200;
default-lease-time 900;

subnet X.Y.145.96 netmask 255.255.255.224 {
  option routers X.Y.145.126;
  range X.Y.145.100 X.Y.145.105;
  next-server X.Y.145.98;
  filename "pxelinux.0"
}

subnet X.Y.145.144 netmask 255.255.255.248 {
  option routers X.Y.145.145;
  range X.Y.145.146 X.Y.145.150;
  next-server X.Y.145.98;
  filename "pxelinux.0"
}
```

The problem we are seeing is that the grub.cfg is grabbing the IP of the `options router` parameter for the variable `pxe_default_server` instead of the `next-server` parameter. This (`pxe_default_server`) is then used to define the variable `net_default_server` parameter and our PXE fails because it is point to the gateway IP instead of the DHCP/PXE server IP. If we edit the grub.cfg file to hard code the `pxe_default_server` parameter to be equal to the IP of the DHCP/PXE server...we can boot fine and pull down an image. Is there a different parameter I should be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grub is surely getting confused, but your dhcpd.confg has issues.

1. You have 2 subnets but you are providing in both the same "next-server" IP that means that for one subnet the TFTP server might not be visible depending on your layout.
2. You are not defining the "broadcast-address" per subnet
3. You are providing PXE data even to not PXE booting clients.

See here an example:
https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/pxe-boot-uefi

> ```
> # DHCP Server Configuration File
> #
> #. see /usr/share/doc/dhcp*/dhcpd.conf.example
> #
> #. see dhcpd.conf(5) man page
>
>
> option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of integer 8;
> option ms-classless-static-routes code 249 = array of integer 8;
> option space pxelinux;
> option pxelinux.magic code 208 = string;
> option pxelinux.configfile code 209 = text;
> option pxelinux.pathprefix code 210 = text;
> option pxelinux.reboottime code 211 = unsigned integer 32;
> option architecture-type code 93 = unsigned integer 16;
> subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
>    option routers 192.168.1.0;
>    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
>    option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
> }
>
> subnet 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
>    option routers 192.168.2.1;
>    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
>    option broadcast-address 192.168.2.255;
>    range 192.168.2.2 192.168.2.254;
>
>    class "pxeclients" {
>      match if substring (option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 9) = "PXEClient";
>      next-server 192.168.1.10;
>      if option architecture-type = 00:07 {
>         filename "shim.efi";
>         } else {
>         filename "pxelinux/pxelinux.0";
>      }
>    }
> }
>
> subnet 192.168.3.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
>    option routers 192.168.3.1;
>    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
>    option broadcast-address 192.168.3.255;
>    range 192.168.3.2 192.168.3.254;
>
>    class "pxeclients" {
>      match if substring (option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 9) = "PXEClient";
>      next-server 192.168.1.10;
>      if option architecture-type = 00:07 {
>         filename "shim.efi";
>         } else {
>         filename "pxelinux/pxelinux.0";
>      }
>    }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
allow bootp;
allow booting;
max-lease-time 1200;
default-lease-time 900;

subnet X.Y.145.96 netmask 255.255.255.224 {
  option routers X.Y.145.126;
  option pxe-server-name X.Y.145.98;
  range X.Y.145.100 X.Y.145.105;
  next-server X.Y.145.98;
  filename "pxelinux.0";
}

subnet X.Y.145.144 netmask 255.255.255.248 {
  option routers X.Y.145.145;
  option pxe-server-name X.Y.145.98;
  range X.Y.145.146 X.Y.145.150;
  next-server X.Y.145.98;
  filename "pxelinux.0";
}
```